# Spring Security keeps giving Error 404 GET /login

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've setup a simple Spring Security app and enabled web security but can't go to the default login page, it keeps raising Error 404. How to resolve this?

Here're my configurations.

**application.properties**

```
# database configs
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# Create Schema automatically
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.sql.init.mode=always
# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
# Custom H2 Console URL
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

##################################################

# session configs
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.session.timeout=86400

##################################################

debug=true

##################################################

# user configs
spring.security.user.name=user
spring.security.user.password=password
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**") // needed to access the h2-console after introducing security module;
            .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin() // needed to access the h2-console after introducing security module
            .and().logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

Any help what's going wrong is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
[nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
[nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

**EDIT 2**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.dsam'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'    // added manually
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'  // added manually
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: 404  for `/login` or `/error`?? ;)

Comment: @xerx593 404 for `/login`

Comment: @xerx593 I've added the error log. Is it because of /error page?

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana Thanks a lot. It worked. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[spring-security](/questions/tagged/spring-security) auto-configures a `/login` page ("view and controller"), but if we want it to work/serve, we **must not**:

```
.loginPage(...)
```

..otherwise we are in charge (to present the view).

From (excellent) [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#loginPage(java.lang.String)) :

> ##### loginPage:
>
> Specifies the URL to send users to if login is required. If used with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter a default login page will be generated when this attribute is **not specified**. ...